# Is it possible to implement the HomeKit Accessory Protocol directly on an Arduino or some other microcontroller without the need for a bridge

Tags: smart-home, microcontrollers, apple-homekit

It seems that all solutions involving homekit make use of a bridge server, so I am confused as to why none of the setups that I can find are implementing homekit directly on the microcontroller.

Is this even possible?
Would some sort of special chip be needed?

Comment: a bridge is a device that connects two separate networks ... you could use a microcontroller ...  basically, the microcontroller would become the bridge